# Finding the time complexity of this method

Tags: java, for-loop, while-loop, time-complexity

I am trying to figure out the time complexity of this code.

My last conclusions about the sections is that the 'while' section the O(logn)
the outer for loop must be under 100 so its O(1) and the inner for loop is O(logn) so i think that the time complexity here is O(logn) in the worst case but i am not sure.

```
public void foo (int n, int m) {
    int i = m;

    while (i > 100) {
        i = i/3;
    }

    for (int k=i ; k>=0; k--) {
        for (int j=1; j<n; j*=2) {
            System.out.print(k + "\t" + j);
        }

        System.out.println();
    }
}
```

Comment: I'm going to highly recommend formatting your code. These random indentations are only going to confuse you and everyone who reads this. PLEASE use brackets to denote closure around your loops. Does the `while` loop encapsulate the `for` loop? Are they separate? This makes a big difference.

Comment: That made a big difference, thanks.

Comment: See how much nicer it is without useless comments and some tastefully-placed whitespace?

Comment: just a suggestion, instead of using `j*=2` use the bitwise left shift: `j<<=1`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Lets break your code step by step :

The first loop i.e,

```
 while (i > 100)  
     i = i/3;
```

runs O(logm) times.

```
for (int k=i ; k>=0; k--) { 
        for (int j=1; j<n; j*=2) {
            System.out.print(k + "\t" + j); 
        } //end inner for loop
        System.out.println(); 
    }
```

The outer loop can run atmost 100 times, and the inner loop i.e

```
for (int j=1; j<n; j*=2) {
      System.out.print(k + "\t" + j); 
} //end inner for loop
```

executes logn times.

total time complexity of for loops = 100logn - > ignoring constants - > logn

Therefore,  the complexity is O(log(m)) + O(log(n))

Comment: Thank you very much, its much better now :)